# How do I select a blank window element with a text inside using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

The element that I want to select out is the "No Requests Remaining" part.

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a//*[contains(text(),"No Requests Remaining")]')
```

The above line of code does not work.

Comment: put url to this page.

Comment: I don't see `<a>` in HTML on image. Did you try `'//*[contains(text(),"No Requests Remaining")]'` ?

Comment: The element with text as **No Requests Remaining** is a `<div>` element you won't be able to `click()` on it. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: What is exception ? use `find_element` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(),"No Requests Remaining")]')`

Since we are expecting only one element, we should use `.find_element_by_xpath()` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If your validation is to check whether the message is displayed or not then you can use the below logic.

```
if (len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[normalize-space(.)='No Requests Remaining']"))>0):
    print("validation pass")
else:
    print("validation failed")
```